# Why use "come" (present simple) in "here they come"?

Tags: tense, present-continuous, present-simple

In this context, why does he use "come"?

> Oh! Quick. Here they **come**. [Oxford English Daily Conversation Episode 2](https://youtu.be/YXf3NmGRfv4?t=24m24s)

Why doesn't he use "are coming" or "have been coming" ?

> They are coming here / Here they are coming.
>
> They have been coming here / Here they have been coming.

**Update:**

Can you please recommend an article or reference where we can use "Simple Present" with *now* events. So I can read and learn more about this usage.

**Update 2:**

I have read this article that describes **[When Should I Use The Present Simple Tense?](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-simple-use.html)**

> **We can also use the present simple for short actions that are happening now**. The actions are so short that they are finished almost as soon as you've said the sentence. This is often used with sports commentary, or in demonstrations.
>   He takes the ball, he runs down the wing, and he scores!
>   First I put some butter in the pan and turn on the cooker.

Is this apply on "Here they *come*"?

Comment: The short answer: this is an idiomatic usage. It is used to signal excitement; positive or negative. Quick. Here they come suggests you have to do something before they see it.

Comment: @Lambie Can you provide me with article describing where we can use "base verb form" with events are happening now, please?

Comment: No, I just know it. Here they come, there they go are idiomatic usages. I just know it as a native speaker and cannot give you a reference. Sorry. Are you writing a grammar by any chance? Why do you need a reference? Just wondering. I suspect it is very, very old: in Shakepeare you get things like: Hark! They come. So maybe it just never left the language.

Comment: @Lambie I need reference just to read more and understand how I can use this tense in right situation.

Comment: Here they come. They they go are structures used in the face of a particular situation. It is idiomatic usage. I just do not know what more I can tell you without extensive research which I am not going to do. It can only be used in the present simple: I suspect it was originally: Hark! They come. In Shakespeare's time, the present simple was often used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply one of the uses of Present Simple:

"In exclamatory sentences beginning with *here* and *there* to express what is actually taking place in the present."

> There she goes!

For other uses and as the source [see here](http://www.atozofenglish.com/2008/09/present-indefinite-simple-tense.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm wondering why good sources (such as Cambridge and Oxford websites) don't mention this common use. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-simple-i-work

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/here-and-there

Answer (score 1):

Shakespeare's usage of Hark! followed by present simple:

Mistress, upon my life, I tell you true; 
I have not breathed almost since I did see it. 
He cries for you, and vows, if he can take you, 
To scorch your face and to disfigure you. 
[Cry within] 
**Hark, hark! I hear him, mistress. fly, be gone**!
Comedy of Errors
[V, 1]

And hark, what noise the general makes! 
Coriolanus
[I, 4]

First Senator

Hark you! they come this way. 
[A march afar] 
All's Well That Ends Well
[III, 5]

Widow

Hark, how they knock! 
Romeo and Juliet

See this BOOK: [that describes this phenomenon under the use of simple present entitled "CURRENT ACTIVITIES: WHEN SAYING IS DOING"](https://books.google.com/books?id=skyftLKdKq0C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=performative%20act%20%2B%20description%20%2B%20%22here%20they%20come%22&source=bl&ots=TlV8DKiDiR&sig=62Rp1dR-Qo-79Glr6pgAzAvQBOc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc4Yj72JzSAhXp7IMKHdccCVUQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=lesson%20five&f=false)

Also, further along in the book is the sentence: /Here they come/ explained in relation to this Current Activity Idea.

This is a type of performative verb, too: /Here they come/ is as if the speaker is actually "doing" the action. In fact, she or he is describing a current activity.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the bare infinitive "come" in

> Here they **come**.
>   There they **go**!

is more of a warning and has the feeling of

> Beware! Here they come!

and is used for emphasis. In your example, the reporter is using to as a *call-to-action*, since they want to film a segment. He could have easily said

> Look! They're coming!

but it would not have the same "feeling". "Here" is not necessary with "coming" since it already implies "coming here" / "coming this way".

I realize this can be confusing since in the same video they also use

> [Look out, she's coming.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXf3NmGRfv4&feature=youtu.be&t=4m35s)

to essentially meaning the same thing.

Comment: It could also be excitement. Here they come! [People you are waiting for].

Comment: Thank you, any recommended reference so I can read more about the subject.

Comment: Sorry, Don't have  reference, you will et to know bout it with more exposure to English, specially AmE.